# Replace cursor with join in SQL Server insert trigger

Tags: sql-server, join, replace, cursor

How do I improve performance by replacing the cursor in the insert trigger with join in SQL Server 2012?

```
create trigger TR-test
on [dbo].[temp]
instead of insert as
begin
   declare @id int

   declare cur cursor fast_forward for 
      select id 
      from inserted 

   open cur
   fetch next from cur into @id

   while @@fetch_status = 0   
   begin
       Print cast(@id as varchar(10))+ ':id number'
       fetch next from cur into @id
   end

   close cur
   deallocate cur
end
```

Comment: You presumably do more than just `PRINT` the data within the loop. *that's the bit of code we'd need to see to make the change*.

Comment: Yes , I have to do a lot of checks for each row in the inserted table . e.g. first I have to check if the table name entered exists in the db ::::: 'declare @tablename as varchar(100)
set @tablename=(select CURRENT_TABLE from inserted)' 

-- check if table exists 
IF not (EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM testdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
                 AND  TABLE_NAME = @tablename))
BEGIN
    Rauserror('Table %s does not exist',16,1,@tablename)
 END
end

Comment: add the formatted code to your question, it'll be much easier to read there

Comment: And if I dont declare cursor the @tablename will not have the expected value and the error would read subquery returned more than 1 row etc. But there is a way to use join and replace the cursor right ?

Comment: `declare @tablename as varchar(100)
set @tablename=(select CURRENT_TABLE from inserted)

IF not (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM testdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
                 AND  TABLE_NAME = @tablename))
BEGIN
    Raiserror('Table %s does not exist',16,1,@tablename)
 END
end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is one method to identify missing tables as a set-based operation, and display the list in the error message.  Note that the table list in the error message will be truncated to 2044 characters followed by "..." if the list size exceeds 2047 characters.  You may be able to leverage set-based processing for the other operations in the trigger but we will need to know the specifics to help.

```
--get list of missing tables
DECLARE @tablelist nvarchar(MAX) =
    (
    SELECT 
        CURRENT_TABLE + ' '
        FROM inserted
        WHERE OBJECT_ID(CURRENT_TABLE, 'U') IS NULL
        FOR XML PATH('')
    );

IF @tablelist IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('All tables do not exist. missing tables: %s', 16, 1, @tablelist);
END;
```

The example below shows how you might validate multiple rows and columns, logging errors to a table and raising an error if errors are found.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ErrorLog(
    ErrorTimestamp datetime2(7) NOT NULL
    ,ErrorMessage nvarchar(200)
    );
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX cdx_ErrorLog ON dbo.ErrorLog(ErrorTimestamp);

DECLARE @ErrorCount int = 0;
DECLARE @ErrorLog TABLE(
    ErrorTimestamp datetime2(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT SYSDATETIME()
    ,ErrorMessage nvarchar(200)
    );

--get list of missing tables
INSERT INTO @ErrorLog(ErrorMessage)
    SELECT 
        'Missing table: ' + CURRENT_TABLE
        FROM inserted
        WHERE OBJECT_ID(CURRENT_TABLE, 'U') IS NULL;
SET @ErrorCount = @ErrorCount + @@ROWCOUNT;

INSERT INTO @ErrorLog(ErrorMessage)
    SELECT 
        'Missing Column1: ' + QUOTENAME(CURRENT_TABLE) + '.' + QUOTENAME(Column1)
        FROM inserted
        WHERE COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(CURRENT_TABLE, 'U'), Column1, 'ColumnId') IS NULL
    UNION ALL SELECT 
        'Missing Column2: ' + QUOTENAME(CURRENT_TABLE) + '.' + QUOTENAME(Column2)
        FROM inserted
        WHERE COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(CURRENT_TABLE, 'U'), Column1, 'ColumnId') IS NULL;
SET @ErrorCount = @ErrorCount + @@ROWCOUNT;

INSERT INTO @ErrorLog(ErrorMessage)
    SELECT
        'Invalid Column1Value: ' + CAST(Column1Value AS varchar(11))
        FROM inserted
        WHERE Column1Value < 0
    UNION ALL SELECT
        'Invalid Column2Value: ' + CAST(Column2Value AS varchar(11))
        FROM inserted
        WHERE Column2Value < 0;
SET @ErrorCount = @ErrorCount + @@ROWCOUNT;

IF @ErrorCount > 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.ErrorLog(ErrorMessage, ErrorTimestamp)
        SELECT ErrorMessage, ErrorTimestamp
        FROM @ErrorLog;
    RAISERROR('%d errors occured', 16, 1, @ErrorCount);
END;
```

Comment: This works wonderfully but I have 55 variables to check so do I have to do this for each and every single one of those ? Also , if I want to log the error I would do `with log` but could I also log the name of the trigger that raised the error ? this is returning null not the trigger name , `declare @ErrorProcedure varchar(50)
 select  @ErrorProcedure = ERROR_PROCEDURE()
    RAISERROR('All tables do not exist. missing tables: %s Error Source: %s', 16, 1, @tablelist,@ErrorProcedure) with Log ;`

Comment: @user3844877, much depends on what you need to do with those 55 columns.  If these are all table names that need to same validation, you could use UNION or UNION ALL.  If a different sort of validation is needed, it may be possible to combine into one or more set-based operations but we need to know the details.  The WITH LOG option requires sysadmin role membership and the message size is more limited.  I suggest a logging table for that purpose.  The trigger name can be obtained with `OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)`.

Comment: They are not all table names though, some are for checking column names and some value comparisons as well . Apologies but I didn't understand what you meant by a logging table ?

Comment: By logging table, I mean you can create a SQL Server table with the columns needed for logging errors (e.g. ErrorTimestamp, ErrorMessage).  You can extend the example I posted to include column and value validation.  Do you want a separate log message for each invalid source column or do you want to combine all the validation errors into a single log message?

Comment: @user3844877: I added an example of a separate message for each validation error to my answer.

Comment: Hi again , Checking the tables works fine but just when I am trying to check if the entered table name exists in a column in a user table I get the same error , `Subquery returned more than 1 value.`Here is what I am adding to to your code `declare @levelname nvarchar(MAX)=
(
    SELECT 
  [LEVEL_NAME] + ' '
        FROM inserted
        WHERE (select i.[LEVEL_NAME]  from inserted i 
  inner join [levels] c on i.LEVEL_NAME=c.LEVEL_NAME) IS NULL
        FOR XML PATH('')
    );
if @levelname is not null 
BEGIN
    RAISERROR();
END`

Comment: I think this is a different issue now so I will add this as a new question .